# Корректно удалить "лишние" диски из Raid1

Tags: linux, grub, raid

Изначально на сервере в софт-рейд1 было объединено 4 диска, два из которых - по ошибке.
Они из массива были удалены, помечены как сбойные, после был создан отдельный массив уже с ними.
В итоге имеем некорректный массив

```
md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      33554304 blocks super 1.0 [4/2] [UU__]
```

и корректный

```
md4 : active raid1 sdc1[0] sdd1[1]
      733878720 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/6 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

Всё бы ничего, но слетел grub и при загрузке имею ошибку 17.

В mdadm.conf разобраться с разделами самостоятельно не могу.

```
DEVICE partitions
MAILADDR root
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.0 UUID=e9eb0c37:0a36b4dd:3f0ce7df:e25da8b6 name=rescue:0
ARRAY /dev/md1 UUID=7469021b:d14f809d:776c2c25:004bd7b2
ARRAY /dev/md/2  metadata=1.0 UUID=befaa2bf:1d2a6e10:74fbf0a4:41d3a8c8 name=rescue:2
ARRAY /dev/md/3  metadata=1.0 UUID=65ff0dc8:457b4abc:3b9d893b:cfe2c44e name=rescue:3
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=0.90 UUID=7469021b:d14f809d:776c2c25:004bd7b2
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.0 name=rescue:0 UUID=e9eb0c37:0a36b4dd:3f0ce7df:e25da8b6
ARRAY /dev/md/2 metadata=1.0 name=rescue:2 UUID=befaa2bf:1d2a6e10:74fbf0a4:41d3a8c8
ARRAY /dev/md/3 metadata=1.0 name=rescue:3 UUID=65ff0dc8:457b4abc:3b9d893b:cfe2c44e
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=0.90 UUID=7469021b:d14f809d:776c2c25:004bd7b2
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.0 name=rescue:0 UUID=e9eb0c37:0a36b4dd:3f0ce7df:e25da8b6
ARRAY /dev/md/2 metadata=1.0 name=rescue:2 UUID=befaa2bf:1d2a6e10:74fbf0a4:41d3a8c8
ARRAY /dev/md/3 metadata=1.0 name=rescue:3 UUID=65ff0dc8:457b4abc:3b9d893b:cfe2c44e
ARRAY /dev/md4 metadata=1.2 name=myserv1:4 UUID=ea6f61b0:9d6b615d:11cb5917:0b5b7b4e
ARRAY /dev/md5 metadata=1.2 name=myserv1:5 UUID=072dbff2:cf729938:439e86c3:c7a04981
```

Comment: Походу строки с `metadata=1.2` лишние. Но лучше ещё погуглить. Мне проверить не на чем и воспроизвести тоже.

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решен полной пересборкой рейда - важных данных не было, потому тянуть и разбираться не стали.